# Nuxtjs : How to disappear the tooltip only when form input is valid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, antdv

In the template below, the `input` disappears when `fullName` is `true`, but I wanna remove the tooltip only. Where should I fix it?

```html
<a-tooltip placement="topRight" trigger="focus" :style="
        fullName === true
          ? { display: 'none' }
          : ''
      ">
    <template slot="title">
      <span>Please fill in your Fullname</span>
    </template>
    <a-input
      @input="checkFullname"
      :placeholder="$t('contact.placeholder.fullName')"
      v-model="dropMessage.full_name"
      :style="
        fullName === false
          ? { backgroundColor: 'rgba(211,47,47,.025)' }
          : ''
      "
    />
</a-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: none` to style your tooltip would cause the tooltip's default slot (the input) to also be hidden, but you don't have to resort to style bindings here.

[`<a-tooltip>` has a `v-model`](https://www.antdv.com/components/tooltip/#Common-API) that can be set to `false` to hide the tooltip. For example, you could use a data prop (e.g., named `tooltipVisible`) as the `v-model` binding, and set it based on the user input in `checkFullname()`:

```html
<template>
  <a-tooltip title="Enter John Doe" v-model="tooltipVisible">
    <a-input @input="checkFullname" v-model="dropMessage.full_name" />
  </a-tooltip>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tooltipVisible: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkFullname() {
      this.tooltipVisible = this.dropMessage.full_name !== 'John Doe'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hiding-tooltip-in-vue-antd-01jo3?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I try it but the tooltip still showing if I click to focus at input again